# Should pdb and ipdb be installed by Anaconda on Windows?

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed Anaconda (python 3) on a Windows 10 machine. Whilst `import pdb` works inside a script I cant use `pdb <script>` on the command line. I would have thought is should work right out of the box. If not, what is the right way to install it on an Anaconda environment? I would also like to use ipdb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

*pdb* package comes with Anaconda 3's Python installation, so when you run `import pdb` in the command line it successfully loads it.

Running `pdb <script>` from command line makes Windows look for a `pdb.exe` executable in any of the paths listed in your PATH environment variable.

As far as I know, *pdb* does not come with a script executable. *ipdb* does.

---

### Solution

PDB:

1. Run `python -m pdb myscript.py` from an Anaconda terminal.

IPDB:

1. Install the ipdb package in your Anaconda Python environment.
2. Try running your script in the command line with `ipdb <script>`.

If the second step does not work for you, this is probably because the anaconda script folder does not appear in your PATH environment variable.

1. Press <kbd>winkey</kbd>
2. Search for *Edit the system environment variables*
3. Click on *environment variables...*.
4. Look for a ***PATH*** variable in either your user or system variables. (If it doesn't exist, create a new variable).
5. Double click it and add a new path pointing to your anaconda *Scripts* folder (for me it's in *%localappdata%\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts*).

And you're done.

Comment: On my Ubuntu machine pdb from the command line worked out of the box (I didn't install Anaconda). It seems they just put a copy of the pdb module in /usr/bin.